# How do I update a Dell U2913WM driver?

Tags: laptop, drivers, multiple-monitors, windows-8

I have an Acer Aspire E1 15.6" Laptop Laptop with Graphics Chipset: Intel HD Graphics 4400.
I am using a VGA cable to extend the screen to my Dell U2913WM (set as primary screen).
The native resolution of the Dell U2913WM is 2560 x 1080 but the highest resolution option for Dell U2913WM that I can select in Windows is 1920 x 1080. Therefore the screen looks stratched and a bit fuzzy.

I was trying to upgrade the driver using the Intel® Driver Update Utility. http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect

I get the following results once I run it:

Current Driver Installed     10.18.10.3355

Newer Driver Available:  15.33.18.64.3496 (10.18.10.3496)

When I download it and start the installation process, I get the following error message: "This operating system is not supported.". I am running on Win8.1 x64. So that shouldn't be the case.

Then I went to the dowload center and selected my laptop, chipset, etc...

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop+graphics+drivers&ProductProduct=4th+Generation+Intel%C2%AE+Core%E2%84%A2+Processors+with+Intel%C2%AE+HD+Graphics+4400&ProdId=3719&LineId=1101&FamilyId=39

When I download the driver and start the installation, I get the same error message.
 "This operating system is not supported."

I double checked my spec under run > dxdiag > display (tabs)

I am pretty sure that I am selecting the driver matching my specs. I just can't install it.

Any idea how to enable the native 2560 x 1080 resolution for the Dell U2913WM display?

Comment: I downloaded and install [this](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=3719&DwnldID=23714&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop+graphics+drivers&ProductProduct=4th+Generation+Intel%c2%ae+Core%e2%84%a2+Processors+with+Intel%c2%ae+HD+Graphics+4400&lang=eng) without a problem. Are you sure your using a 64-bit installation of Windows? Most OEM products don't come with it. I have a Haswell desktop product and Windows 8.1, Windows 8.0, and Windows 7 boot disks and it installed on all 3 of them.

Comment: Perhaps the installer is/is not being run in compatibility mode? Right click > Properties and check.

Comment: You really should use the drivers released by Acer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ramhound suggests, try/use the Acer-supplied video adapter drivers, as they may have tweaked the video adapter to a point where the generic Intel drivers don't work anymore.

Having said that, you're current driver is SO close in versions that there won't be any difference in feature support even if you did get that newer one installed.

So I think your Acer's external VGA port just doesn't support the resolution you want, which is not uncommon.

Comment: Thanks, guys for your tips. I am pretty sure now that it's the VGA post not supporting the resolution. I plugged in an HDMI cable and the I had the 2560 x 1080 resolution instantly available in my settings.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had this problem as well (monitor could not achieve native 2560 x 1080 resolution).

As for me, the problem is not in the driver, but in the monitor input source.

I just build a pc (I bought the components and assembled it myself), here are the relevant parts

- Asus H97M-E Motherboard
- Intel Core i7 4790 (which comes with Intel HD Graphics 4600)
- Dell UltraSharp U2913WM Monitor
- Windows 8.1 Pro

The monitor is connected to the PC via the supplied DVI and HDMI cable (I connected two cables at the same time).

Ok, the monitor supports up to 2560x1080, but Windows keep saying the maximum I can go is 1920 x 1080, something is obviously wrong.

So I googled a bit and found out that Asus H97M-E DVI port only support 1920x1080, but thankfully the HDMI port supports up to 2560 x 1600 @ 60Hz!  What a relief!

However Windows insists that I have only one monitor (connected via DVI-D), it does not detect that same monitor connected via HDMI! So I am stuck with 1920x1080.

I spent about and hour or two reinstalling drivers, restarting windows, tried different HDMI cables, etc... nothing works... until I accidentally pressed on the monitor OSD control and this appeared!..

[image: Dell UltraSharp U2913WM OSD Button]

After I select HDMI as the Input Source, Windows now display as 2560x1080 capable, horray!

I guess God took pity on me and interfered with my destiny, so He/She pushed my finger on that button to help me... thanks God...